# Cypress config hook issue with running a node script

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

I have this hook in my `cypress.config.ts`:

```
...
            on('after:run', async () => {
                console.log('override after:run')
                await exec('touch ./cypress/reports/test.txt')
                await exec(
                    'npx jrm ./cypress/reports/junitreport.xml ./cypress/reports/junit/*.xml'
                )

                await afterRunHook()
            })
...
```

The `touch` command works fine, but the `jre` don't produce the `junitreport.xml` file or any other output.

If I run `npx jrm ./cypress/reports/junitreport.xml ./cypress/reports/junit/*.xml` on the command line it works just fine.

I have also tried with `./node_modules/.bin/jre` instead of `npx jrm`

as well as `node ./node_modules/.bin/jre` but to no avail.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `execSync()` instead of `exec()` works:

```
            on('after:run', async () => {
                console.log('override after:run')
                await execSync(
                    'node ./node_modules/.bin/jrm ./cypress/reports/junitreport.xml ./cypress/reports/junit/*.xml > ./cypress/reports/jrm-log.txt 2>&1'
                )

                await afterRunHook()
            })
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use `execSync()` you can drop the async/await decoration.

In the original code, `exec()` ***returns no promise***, so `await` has no effect. It uses callbacks to respond.

> child_process.exec(command[, options][, **callback**])

You could use [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to make `exec()` work in the context of `after:run`.

```js
const util = require('util');

on('after:run', async () => {
  await util.promisify(exec(''npx jrm ...'))
  ...
```